# sharepoint rest api credentials

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint

I'm triggering an external web page outside of sharepoint which needs to read lists using the sharepoint web api.

```
        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/web/lists");
        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        //endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

I can access the API using chrome if I'm logged in but I suspect I need the access token line.. but can't seem to find a way to populate it.

Currently it returns:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set credential of HttpWebRequest.

Here you go:

```
            HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/web/lists");

            string password = "XXXXX";
            string userName = "XXXX";
            SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
            {
                secureString.AppendChar(c);
            }
            endpointRequest.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);

            //.........
```

Comment: I keep getting socket exceptions from a microsoft ip address (looks like azure):   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...

Comment: This is an application accessing a sharepoint 365 site.  The URL works in chrome and with a rest api tester

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online, it can work with my answer above because i have tested.

If you are using SharePoint 2013/2010/2016, the code will be as below.

```
        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/web/lists");

        string password = "XXXXX";
        string userName = "XXXX";
        string domain = "XXX"
        endpointRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

        //.........
```